# How to get blockchain length

Tags: tezos-client, syncing

I send rpc calls to a node through `tezos-client` and I would like to know the length, or the height, of the blockchain so I can see if it is synced and, if not, how much time is remaining. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head`. Look for the value of the `level` key under the `header` key in the outputted json.

The output data is quite big, so you can use this:

`tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head | grep level | head -1`

Comment: Since all output of the RPC is JSON, you should look into using `jq` rather than grep/head. Far more powerful for command-line filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You can also call `tezos-client get timestamp` repeatedly: it will give you the timestamp of the most recently received block. You'll get an idea on where you're at and how long you have left to synchronize. If you want to synchronize the full state of the blockchain, this might take a long time. Look into [snapshots](https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/snapshots.html) to get into sync faster. You can find [snapshots](https://snapshots.tulip.tools/#/) here.